# TSQL "multi-part identifier x could not be found" when updating fields in a temp table

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-update, alter

I created a temp table like this:

```
SELECT 
    email_key, 
    Best_pn_ee_active_pbm, 
    Best_pn_ee_active_pbm_pub, 
    Best_pn_ee_active_pbm_status, 
    Best_pn_ee_inactive_pbm, 
    Best_pn_ee_inactive_pbm_pub, 
    Best_pn_ee_inactive_pbm_status
INTO #kjs_univ_sample
FROM view_univ_email
```

I subsequently added some columns to be populated later:

```
ALTER TABLE #kjs_univ_sample
ADD Best_pn_ee_active_pbm_my varchar(10), 
    Best_pn_ee_active_pbm_status_my varchar(10), 
    Best_pn_ee_active_pbm_pub_my varchar(10), 
    Best_pn_ee_inactive_pbm_my varchar(10), 
    Best_pn_ee_inactive_pbm_status_my varchar(10), 
    Best_pn_ee_inactive_pbm_pub_my varchar(10)
```

I then tried to update the fields I just added:

```
UPDATE #kjs_univ_sample
SET 
    a.Best_pn_ee_active_pbm_my =        b.s_pbm_account_key, 
    a.best_pn_ee_active_pbm_pub_my =    b.s_pub_code,
    a.best_pn_ee_active_pbm_status_my = b.s_subscription_status
FROM #kjs_univ_sample as a
RIGHT JOIN #kjsemailcount as b ON a.email_key = b.email
WHERE a.email_key = b.email
  AND b.counted = '1'
```

The issue is that all of 4 columns that were added via the `ALTER` are showing the error

> 'The multi-part identifier "" could not be bound.

I've tried using the alias 'a' in the `Update` line and not using alias at all.  When I type the name of the fields I want to update it shows the drop-down but none of the fields added by the `ALTER` are there.

It's like it doesn't see them. A `Select *` will show them however. Any ideas?

Comment: Try leaving out the `a.` on the `set`.

Comment: I think you want a `LEFT` join instead of `RIGHT`, and you don't need to repeat your `ON` clause in your `WHERE` clause.

Comment: Removing the a. doesn't change anything.  If i use the a. and then keep typing it suggests all the other fields in the temp table except the ones I want.  As if it doesn't see them.

Comment: Change `UPDATE #kjs...` to `UPDATE a`, and also put a `GO` between the `ALTER` and the `UPDATE`. I suspect the error is simply a compile-time error, because SSMS is trying to parse the whole script in one - pun intended - `GO`.

Comment: I'm actually running these one at a time in series.  :(

Comment: even something as simple as 

update #kjs_univ_sample 
set Best_pn_ee_active_pbm_my = Best_pn_ee_active_pbm 
where Best_pn_ee_active_pbm_pub = 'PN'

has the issue. it's as if the fields added with ther ALTER are not visible for the UPDATE

Answer (score 0):

This code worked:

```
update #kjs_univ_sample 
set Best_pn_ee_active_pbm_my = b.s_pbm_account_key, 
best_pn_ee_active_pbm_pub_my = b.s_pub_code,
best_pn_ee_active_pbm_status_my = b.s_subscription_status
from #kjs_univ_sample as a
right join #kjsemailcount as b
on a.email_key = b.email
where a.email_key = b.email
and b.counted = '1'
```

I removed the a. as previously suggested by @Gordon-Linoff.  It did not remove the warning messages but it did end up working.

Comment: I prefer to leave the `a.` in place for each set column, but change `update #kjs_univ_sample` to `update a`.